# Using Django-Taggit in Django Rest Framework 3.13.1 with Django 4.0.2 with Error "Invalid json list" in Serializing Tags Model Attribute

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, django-taggit

Older solutions uses [django-taggit-serializer](https://github.com/glemmaPaul/django-taggit-serializer) which is now been [deprecated](https://github.com/glemmaPaul/django-taggit-serializer/issues/54) and doesn't work with the version I have.

I have already done what the [documentation](https://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/serializers.html) says regarding the integration with DRF.

However, I am getting this error:

> b'{"tags":["Invalid json list. A tag list submitted in string form must be valid json."]}'

[image error in drf browsable api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ggcT.png)

### Here is my code

**viewset.py**

```
class AnnouncementViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """Announcement ViewSet."""

    queryset = Announcement.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AnnouncementSerializer
    lookup_field = "slug"
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser, IsAuthorOrReadOnly]

    def get_permissions(self):
        """Return permissions."""
        if self.action in ["create", "update", "partial_update", "destroy"]:
            self.permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
        else:
            self.permission_classes = [IsAuthorOrReadOnly]
        return super().get_permissions()
```

**models.py**

```
class Announcement(models.Model):
    """Announcement model."""

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    title = models.CharField(_("title"), max_length=255, unique=True)
    content = models.TextField(_("content"))
    is_featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(
        upload_to="announcement/thumbnail", default="announcement/thumbnail/default.jpg"
    )
    tags = TaggableManager(_("tags"))
    slug = models.SlugField(_("Slug"), max_length=255, unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class AnnouncementSerializer(TaggitSerializer, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = TagListSerializerField()
        
    class Meta:
        model = Announcement
        exclude = ["slug"]

        extra_kwargs = {
            "url": {"view_name": "api:announcement-detail", "lookup_field": "slug"}
        }
```

What I have tried so far:

```
tags = "my-tag"

tags = ["tag1", "tag2"]
```

I even wrote a test:

**tests.py**

```
def test_announcement_create_url(
    self, api_client: Client, admin_user
):
    api_client.force_login(admin_user)
    response = api_client.post(
        reverse("api:announcement-list"),
        {
            "title": "This is a new announcement",
            "content": "This is the content of the new announcement",
            "is_featured": "True",
            "tags": ["tag1", "tag2"],
        },
    )
    print(response.content)
    assert response.status_code == status.HTTP_201_CREATED
```

But it produces the same error.

I also found this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/glemmaPaul/django-taggit-serializer/issues/35) but again, django-taggit-serializer is deprecated and is not being maintained anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my own answer. The cause of the error is my `tags` Model Attribute.

If your Model Attribute is named `tags` then you need to do this in order to submit or tests your API query:

**Browsable API**

```
{
    "tags": ["tag1", "tag2"]
}
```

**Python Code**

```
{
    "tags": '["tag1", "tag2"]'
}
```

Some fields are omitted for brevity. Make sure to include the required fields needed by your serializer.